# Handle Dictionary like String conversion to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, pyspark

I'm a pyspark  dataframe as

Below code :-

```
 data=[[1,"sai","ram",'"color":"red","green","blue","flower":"rose","tulip"'],
    [2,"avi","kumar",'"color":"grey","black","white","flower":"roses","tulips"'] , 
[3,"ravi","prakash",'"color":"pink","cherry red","blue","flower":"rosey","tulipey"']
  ]
data_columns=["id","f_name","l_name","feature_stack"]
d=spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=data_columns)
d.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

i wanted to convert this dictonary type string to a dataframe as:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please do not post code as image but as text.

Comment: Noted & EDITED!...Kindly Check....

Answer (score 1):

Try with **`regexp_extract`** function to extract **color,flower** from the **feature_stack** data.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

d.withColumn("color",regexp_extract(col("feature_stack"),'"color":(.*),"flower"',1)).\
withColumn("flower",regexp_extract(col("feature_stack"),'"flower":(.*)',1)).\
show(10,False)
```

Comment: Its Working as expected...will move to next steps....